# Understanding Overpower protection specifics

Tags: power-supply, circuit-protection

I am trying to understand how a particular ac-dc converter behaves in an overpower situation. The converter is the [SRP-25](https://www.ipdpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/SRP-25%20Specs.pdf) series from Integrated Power.

From the datasheet (linked above), I see this:

[image]

The protection is described as 'Outputs cycle on/off, auto recovery.' I am looking to understand specifically what would happen with a potential failure mode where the load impedance develops a partial short, leading to too much power being drawn. I interpret this datasheet description to mean that the output shuts off in such an overpower situation. I am not exactly sure what 'auto recovery' means. Does this language have a standard interpretation, such as meaning that the output is shut off until the input power is cycled? Or does it mean that the converter would attempt a reset on its own after some time?

I looked for this info in the operating instructions, but found no reference to it there either.

Comment: I would interpret "auto recovery" as "automatic reset." The converter resets itself after some time, likely a short time. There have been many questions here about DC motors repeatedly attempting to start and immediately stopping when powered from an electronic power supply. That is usually a protected supply that automatically resets, used with a motor that requires more starting current than the supply is designed for. So that feature seems to be included in most electronic converter power supplies.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.